# Date Formats When Reading Excel with SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, script-component

experts!
I've got two similar Excel files (xlsm) as templates. Both have sheets with Date column.
Visible format for both files when use Excel is "10-Aug-20".
But when I read these files with SSIS process with Script Component Source using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 with "IMEX=1"... ta-da... some I see as expected, but some are 10.08.2020 00:00:00
This causes me a lot of pain because I will process files from both US (MM/dd/yyyy) and German (dd.MM.yyyy) date formats and would like to have locale-independent date format to process dates same way.
How can I force excel to give or ssis to read a correct date format.

Any suggestion how to see both files same programmaticly is most wanted and highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the script component (as Transformation) to transform the data by using [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__)

```
  string dateString = "10-Aug-20";
  string format = "dd-MMM-yy";
  DateTime dateTime;
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, "en-US",DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))//if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, "de-DE",DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that the input data is ambiguous. Is 10.08.2020 10 Aug or 8th Oct?

Comment: i see, you do not even know this should be treated as US or DE... no other indicator of flag?